# Supervisord - NGINX stop OSError

Tags: nginx, supervisord

I ran into an error when trying to stop `NGINX` using `supervisord`.

To start `NGINX` without error from `supervisord` I had to prepend `sudo` to the nginx command in `supervisord.conf`:

```
[supervisord]
[program:nginx]
command=sudo nginx -c %(ENV_PWD)s/configs/nginx.conf
```

When I run this:

```
$ supervisord -n
2017-02-09 12:26:06,371 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2017-02-09 12:26:06,372 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2017-02-09 12:26:06,372 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2017-02-09 12:26:06,373 INFO supervisord started with pid 22152
2017-02-09 12:26:07,379 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 22155
2017-02-09 12:26:08,384 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)

^C # SIGINT: Should stop all processes

2017-02-09 13:59:08,550 WARN received SIGINT indicating exit request
2017-02-09 13:59:08,551 CRIT unknown problem killing nginx (22155):Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ocervell/.virtualenvs/ndc-v3.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor/process.py", line 432, in kill
    options.kill(pid, sig)
  File "/Users/ocervell/.virtualenvs/ndc-v3.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor/options.py", line 1239, in kill
    os.kill(pid, signal)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

Same when using `supervisorctl` to stop the process:

```
$ supervisorctl stop nginx
FAILED: unknown problem killing nginx (22321):Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ocervell/.virtualenvs/ndc-v3.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor/process.py", line 432, in kill
    options.kill(pid, sig)
  File "/Users/ocervell/.virtualenvs/ndc-v3.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor/options.py", line 1239, in kill
    os.kill(pid, signal)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

Is there a workaround for this ?

Comment: The question is, why do you want to start nginx with supervision? It daemonizes, which means it exits and supervisord will detect that as failure (it isn't). It has to be ran with sudo because it binds to low port numbers (80 and 443). Rethink your decision to supervise that daemon. To make nginx run so supervisor can do its job, you must tell it not to daemonize. [Refer to this, from nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/faq/daemon_master_process_off.html).

Comment: Starting nginx works, I have 'daemon off' in the nginx config. The problem is how to kill it with supervisor. The reason I want to start / stop nginx with supervisor is that I need a on/off switch for all the processes I am running (webservers, redis, rabbitmq, etc...) including nginx.

Comment: Just trying to stab in the dark here - `sudo supervisorctl stop nginx`, did you try that yet?

Comment: Yes it returns the same error `OSError`

Answer (score 0):

> If a process created by supervisord creates its own child processes, supervisord cannot kill them.
>
> ...
>
> The pidproxy program is put into your configuration’s $BINDIR when supervisor is installed (it is a “console script”).[<sup>[1]</sup>](http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html#pidproxy-program)

So what you have to do is changing your supervisord configuration like this:

```
[program:nginx]
command=/path/to/pidproxy /path/to/nginx-pidfile sudo nginx -c %(ENV_PWD)s/configs/nginx.conf
```

This may not work either, since the nginx process is create by `sudo`. But let's try it first.

Comment: Tried running `pidproxy /tmp/nginx.pid sudo nginx -c \`pwd\`/configs/nginx.conf` in my terminal, didn't complain but I don't see the nginx process running.